# PIV or GIDS compatible token availability

Tags: smartcard, windows-8

I am researching smartcards for corporate implementation and have hit a small bump. We need to support Windows RT, and Windows RT does not support Windows minidrivers for smartcards. Instead, it only supports PIV or GIDS compliant devices (cf. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849637.aspx#BKMK_WinRTsupport).

I know from research that GIDS is primarily Microsoft, while PIV is a US Government standard that has a civilian equivalent PIV-I (*note: this is deliberately oversimplifying*).

I have only found two ready, order online sources for PIV-compatible tokens (https://www.goldkey.com/order-desk/ and http://boutique.gemalto.com/), and none for GIDS-compatible tokens.

What other options are available that meet these needs without jumping through a lot of hoops? I just want to buy a single token quickly to experiment with, and then later purchase one-offs. I want to do online ordering with a credit card. I can do this with more traditional smartcards at lots of places (e. g. https://www.smartcardfocus.us/).